# Why do NoSql databases want data to be as flat as possible? Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, nosql

Why do NoSQL databases want the data to be as flat as possible? Especially in the case of firebase. Can anyone provide read or write calculations to show the differences in I/O between relatively flat databases and relatively deep, multi-level, databases?

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 1):

I what comes to Firebase Realtime Database, it's much more than performance, it's about information retrieval strategy.

You are free to save the ids of every liker of a specific post nested in the post structure, but if you feel you don't need to retrieve all this information every time you get a post (let's suppose you query a list of posts only to show as a summary cards), then you won't want to have it nested, but flat under a "post_likes/{postId}" node for example.

Remember that in the Firebase Realtime Database you can't filter out the nodes you don't want to receive. At the moment you retrieve a node, you get it all the way deep down the structure.

Think about the same example now, but for comments. The same thing apply, so we could structure our comments under a "post_comments/{postId}" node and only retrieve it when we are willing to show the comments.

Comment: Great answer. Those are indeed the most common reasons.